# Python and JSON Conditional Optimization

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use Python to classify businesses based on a number of attributes.  The data pointing to what attributes each business category has is stored in a json file, such as:

```
{
  "type1": {
    "business_code": [
      1,
      3,
      5
    ],
    "business_code2": [
      2,
      7,
      11
    ],
    "business_name": [
      "pizza",
      "bagel store"
    ]
  },
  "type2": {
    "business_code": [
      4,
      18,
      23
    ],
    "business_code2": [
      8,
      16,
      72
    ],
    "business_name": [
      "bank",
      "credit union"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I'd like to use python to classify them in a function which takes business_code, business_code2, and business_name as arguments, like

```
with open('json_test.json') as f:
    j_test = json.load(f)

def classify_business(business_code, business_code2, business_name):
    for key, _ in j_test:
        if (business_code in j_test[key]['business_code'] or
                    business_code2 in j_test[key]['business_code2'] or
                    business_name in j_test[key]['business_name']):
            break
        else:
            continue
    return key
```

The issue is that I have many classes, and the conditionals are not always the same for each class. For example class1 may need a match on business_code AND (business_code2 or business_name) and class2 may need a match on only (business_code OR business_code2 OR business_name).

I'd like to know if there is any cleaner way to do the conditionals in the Python function without writing out a new one explicitly for each class.  Maybe something that could be done in the JSON file preferably.

Answer (score 0):

`classify_business` should take a function that tests whether a business matches the criteria.

```
def classify_business(j_test, tester):
    for key, business in j_test:
        if tester(business):
            return key
    return None
```

Then you can call it with a `lambda`

```
classify_business(j_test, lambda b: return business_code in b['business_code'] or business_code2 in b['business_code2'] or business_name in b['business_name'])
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for.  The different conditionals required change based on the classes of businesses in the json file.  So for each business, as you go through the business types sequentially to check whether it belongs to each of them, you'll need different combinations of (and)s and (or)s for each category, but they won't change based on the input business being categorized.  Sorry if I wasn't clear about that.

Comment: You need to clarify the question, and show how you intend to use this. You mention classes, but there's no class code in the question.

Comment: Apologies.  When I said "class" and "classify" I just meant type, not anything related to objects.  I changed the words class and class2 in the json code to type and type2.

Comment: What I mean is you need to show how the different combinations of conditions are related to the types. Where are they coming from? Your basic choice is to either use functions that implement the conditions, or a complicated data structure that represents the conditions, which your classify function will then have to parse.